# Python 3 error: No module named bs4

Tags: python-3.x, python-module, beautifulsoup

I have written this code:

```
from urllib.request import *
smhw='https://www.showmyhomework.co.uk/todos/issued'
page = urlopen(smhw)
print(page)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print(soup.prettify())
```

However, when I run it I get this error message:

```
<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x000001CACE879438>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Bill's stuff\ws.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

There is a module named bs4, so I don't know what to do. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Did you install it: pip install BeautifulSoup4?

Comment: Also are you running a virtualenv?

Comment: Maybe the module is installed for a different verion of python than the one executing your code.

Comment: @ApoorvKansal: I am not running a virtualenv. How would you install it?

Comment: Are you using Pycharm? if yes, check this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59125982/8919960).

Answer (score 0):

**For Python 3**

follow these steps:

1. Download **Python 3** from https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. Open the installer
3. Check **Add Python 3.5 to PATH**
4. Customize installation
5. Check **pip**
6. check **install for all users**
7. check **Add Python to environment variables**
8. HIT INSTALL!!

Now download this file

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9JWvFYLLVfpZW1BZ2lncm91aWc

1. Open command Prompt as **Administrator** and run this file **python pip.py**
2. Open command Prompt as **Administrator** again and execute **pip install beautifulsoup4**
3. Run your code,It would be working fine now

Comment: which version of python you are using ?

Comment: I am using Python 3.

Comment: hey Bill I have update the answer please follow the steps and you willl be able to execute the code.

Comment: are you getting the same error No module named 'bs4' ?