# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

When I try to import BeautifulSoup like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

And when I run my code, I've this error message.
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4`

If someone know how to resolve this problem, it's will be great !

```
import os
import csv
import requests
import bs4

requete = requests.get("https://url")
page = requete.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

h1 = soup.find("h1", {"class": "page_title"})
print(h1.string)
```

EDIT :
I don't know why but if I run my code with python3.6 it's doesn't work, but with python3.7 or 2.7 it's good. Thanks for your help

Comment: just do `import bs4`. Or if you leave as `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`, you have somewhere in your code something like: `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`. Change that to: `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`

Comment: Did you pip install it? `pip install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: Yes, I've install via pip and pip3

Answer (score 4):

Do a `pip install bs4` and that will solve your error. If you have different versions of Python installed, try with `pip2` or `pip3` as per your requirement.

```
pip2 install bs4 # for Python2
pip3 install bs4 # for Python3
```

Comment: I don't know why but if I run my code with python3.6 it's doesn't work, but with python3.7 or 2.7 it's good. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PyCharm, close and restart PyCharm. Then hover mouse cursor over **`bs4`**, until the red bulb shows up. Use the first intention action - `"Install beautifulsoup"`, then PyCharm will take care of the problem from there.

I had the same issue, and the intention action won't work until I reboot PyCharm.

Comment: Same issue here with Pycharm, I could install it either with conda or pip, although, I couldn't import it. Using the red bulb solved it (even without reboot), but why?

Answer (score 1):

You either a) have not installed BeautifulSoup or b) without seeing your code, can only guess you have `bs4` in your code:

Ie.

`soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`

Should change that to:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`

**OR**

You can keep:

`soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`

but then you need to have the import as:

`import bs4`

**FULL CODE: OPTION 1**

```
import os
import csv
import requests
import bs4     #<-----------------------NOTICE

requete = requests.get("https://url")
page = requete.content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page)  #<-----------------------NOTICE

h1 = soup.find("h1", {"class": "page_title"})
print(h1.string)
```

**FULL CODE: OPTION 2**

```
import os
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   #<-----------------------NOTICE

requete = requests.get("https://url")
page = requete.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)  #<-----------------------NOTICE

h1 = soup.find("h1", {"class": "page_title"})
print(h1.string)
```

Comment: Yes, I already do your first options and when I try your second options I've this message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'`

Comment: I don't know why but if I run my code with python3.6 it's doesn't work, but with python3.7 or 2.7 it's good. Thanks for your help

Comment: I think BeautifulSoup has got inbuilt class support as `class_`, why not use `class_= "page_title"` instead of `{"class": "page_title"}`?

Comment: @InfectedDrake, you are correct. You could use that syntax, and I have nothing against it. For me, it's just my own preference.